# Getting the name of the NestJS module where a service is defined from the ModuleRef instance

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to get the name of the module where a service is defined in NestJS, but I'm having trouble finding a way to do this. I can inject a reference to the ModuleRef in the service's constructor, but I can't seem to find any utilities for getting the module name.

Here's an example of my ConfigService class:

```js
class ConfigService implements OnModuleInit {
  tag: string;

  toString(): string {
    return this.tag;
  }

  constructor(@Inject(ModuleRef) private moduleRef: ModuleRef) {
    console.log(this.moduleRef);
    this.tag = tagGenerator.next(`ConfigService`);
  }
  onModuleInit() {
    tagGenerator.next('ConfigService->onModuleInit');
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get the name of the module from the ModuleRef instance in the service's constructor or onModuleInit() method?